# When should I use decorator / observer?

Tags: design-patterns, decorator, observer-pattern

There is these two pattern : observer and decorator. Both enables me to add an action after something was done (or before for the decorator). But their implementation differs. So when should I use a decorator or an observer.

So far I came up with this :

- decorator : add business functionnality to a service that'll change the state of the entities used by the decorated service.
- observer : update the view model / gui, connect with infrastructure service, change the state of other entities

For instance in a booking level I have a booking entity, the first service will create the booking and mark the accomodation as not available :

- sending an email to the customer / owner : observer
- using customers cc for automating the payment : decorator
- updating the view/cache with accomodations availabilities : observer
- mark the booking as "must be validated or validated" : decorator

Am I right ?

Answer (score 2):

These two patterns are not similar. You should use Decorator if you need to additional responsibilities to an object while *keeping the same interface*. I don't see why would you need to keep the same interface in this case, therefore I am against Decorator.

Observer is fine when you want to be notified of a change in another object (for example to "add an action after something was done"), although there could be simpler ways.

Comment: As I said, for me they help for the same purpose : adding functionality to your existing business flow. Even if it's not the same kind of pattern, the purpose is the same.

Comment: If you only want to "add functionality", there are lots of ways to do it, possibly you don't need any design patterns. OO design patterns have specific and unique purposes and use cases, and they should be used only in those cases.

Answer (score 1):

Observer is a **behavioral pattern**.
Decorator is a **structural pattern**.

Using **observer** implements event handling (it binds some method calls of different classes with each other).
Using **decorator** you can change (extend) features of some object at a runtime (it changes the objects themselves - thanks to polymorphysm, so same methods may be overridden etc).

In your example booking application I would use both patterns (as you presented it).